# How can I store root ginger for maximum shelf life?

Tags: storage-method, storage-lifetime, ginger

I have root ginger which sometimes dries out and goes a bit wrinkly.  Currently I just store it on the side in a bowl.  Is there a better way to store it to maximise its shelf life?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It will definitely last longer in the refrigerator than at room temperature.  You can also freeze it whole and then grate off what is needed as you need it.

Comment: I use a microplane to grate frozen ginger. It gives a 'snow' of ginger that melts invisibly into a dish.

Answer (score 6):

Fine Cooking did an experiment and found [unpeeled in zip-top bag, in the crisper of your fridge](http://www.finecooking.com/articles/storing-ginger.aspx) lasted two months.  They had longer time with peeled, in vodka, in the fridge, but that's more effort in my opinion.

Still Tasty seems to [agree on a bag in the fridge](http://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/17263), but claim only 2-3 weeks for it.

Comment: This is what I do, and I very rarely have a problem. (I almost always go through say an eight inch piece of ginger in a few weeks).

Answer (score 3):

I read in Madhur Jaffrey's book that burying ginger in sandy soil was a popular storage method, but have never tried it myself.

Answer (score 2):

I put plain un-peeled ginger in white wine in a mason jar.  It lasts a LONG time, many weeks.  The wine is also useful when you need a little burst of ginger but don't feel like dealing with the root.