# How long does ginger root last?

Tags: storage-lifetime, spices, ginger

I bought ginger root months ago, and I didn't use all of it. I've kept it in the fridge and it still seems good. How long will it last?

Comment: See also: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3549/how-can-i-store-root-ginger-for-maximum-shelf-life

Answer (score 6):

[Eat By Date](http://www.eatbydate.com/other/spices/how-long-does-ginger-last-shelf-life/) claims a shelf life of about one month, in the refrigerator, which matches my experience.

Ginger root is a living rhizome, and is the plant's way of storing energy to grow later.  As long as it is firm, not slimy, with no signs of a mold, with a good aroma, you should be able to use it.

Answer (score 3):

You could store it in the freezer for a few months longer (about 3 or so) the next time you pick some up. Since I typically grate it, I haven't noticed any texture issues. Otherwise, I find it lasts 4-6 weeks normally in the fridge.